# How to implement Serializable to a super class which you don't have access to?

Tags: java, maven, serialization, deserialization

Say there are two class foo and bar

bar extends foo but foo is a dependency that was added through maven. So I don't have access to foo's code but I want to serialize it for caching reasons. I want to know is there a way to serialize the foo class without changing the code inside foo it self ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to serialize `Foo` instances (note the use of naming conventions) or `Bar` instances only? If the latter you could just have `Bar` implement `Serializable` if the former you'd have to write your own serialization code (see here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220554/how-to-serialize-a-third-party-non-serializable-final-class-e-g-googles-latln)

Comment: I want to serialize the foo instance

Comment: In that case the `Bar extends Foo` example is misleading and probably unnecessary anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize foo by using a third party `Jboss serialization` API.

excerpt from [Jboss Serialization Website](http://serialization.jboss.org/) **JBossSerialization is a new approach to java-serialization.**

Check this [link](http://java.sys-con.com/node/2678144) for an example.